# gmailにおけるSPF recordの設定の仕方を教えてください。

Tags: gmail, mail

Pythonを使って、SMTPでgmailのサーバから、gmail用にマークアップされたメールを送信しようとしています。
[Event Reservation  |  Email Markup  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation)

しかし、上記のサンプルコードをhtmlメールに埋め込んで、自分自身のgmailアドレスから、自分自身のメールアドレスに送信しても、markupの結果が表示されませんでした。
そこで、色々調べた所、stack overflowにて同じような質問を見つけました。
[Google email markup not showing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564946/google-email-markup-not-showing)

上記の質問の回答として、

> v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

をSPF recordとして使用して下さいと書いてあるのですが、
SMPTでgmailのサーバからメールを送信したい場合は、
このSPFレコードはどのように設定すれば良いのでしょうか？
教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

SPFレコードは、DNSへ設定しましす。

```
DNSへの設定例
 hoge.jp.  IN TXT v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

メールアドレスのなりすましなどを防ぐ為に、そのドメインからの送信が許可されているサーバから送信されているのかどうかを判断に使用されます。

Comment: さん　コメントありがとうございます。　具体的に自分のgmailのアカウントから、同じgmailのアカウントにメールを送りたい場合、どのようにSPFをDNSに設定するかを教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: SPFレコードはメールの送信者のドメインにTXTレコードとして定義します。Gmail(@gmail.com)であれば、gmail.comのドメインに設定するものなのでこれはGoogleしかできません。